# Introduction/Text on android permissions / shell

Tags: android, shell, permissions, executable, su

Here is my problem:
Using the Team Win recovery mode, I tried two things. One works and I do not understand why the other one does not:

1. From the terminal, using vi, i made the file /system/bin/tteesst, which is:

   #!/system/bin/sh

   echo Hi

I did a chmod 755.

2. I copied the su-file from /supersu to /system/bin/su
   I did a chmod 4755, and set its group to 'shell'

( su works in recovery mode, and whoami yields root)

But when I start my system (Lineage OS ), and I open a terminal, I get this:

```
    jfvelte:/ $/system/bin/tteesst

    Hi                                                                (---OK---)

    jfvelte:/ $touch /system/bin/teesstt
    touch '/system/bin/teesstt': read-only file system                (---OK---)

    jfvelte:/ $ /system/bin/su
    /system/bin/sh: /system/bin/su : not found                        (---NOT OK---)

    jfvelte: ls /system/bin/teesstt /system/bin/su
    ls: /system/bin/su: No such file or directory                     (---NOT OK---)
    /system/bin/teesstt
```

The first two commands do what I expected, but the next two do not. Why can't the user see the su file ?

```
  (solved)
```

partly: I had to install the supersu-package twice, once again in the lineage OS, and also give the terminal access to root. Remaining problem is to find out if I can put a password on su

Comment: Not an expert, but maybe those are different partitions. What'd you get if executing `ls -l /system/bin | grep su` NOT in recovery mode? And traditionally `su` is located under `/system/xbin` in Android. Moreover, you do not need `su` to run a script, just execute `sh /path/to/script`.

Comment: I put another su in xbin, but that does not help. I need su for its own sake, the shell script was just a test to see if i can install anything at all from recovery mode and run it. So, I can. But not su. [ls -l] does not show it in the directory outside recovery mode. ,br. BTW I see i forget to put the main question first: is there a good manual on where permissions are stored in android, so that I can check and/or change stuff there